# Adding to a struct from inside a loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops, struct

I'm sorry if there are other threads that ask this question, but I unfortunately don't understand enough C++ yet to understand most of them.

I'm trying to use a loop to ask the user a series of questions, and then save those responses in a struct.

```
struct custOrder
{
    char fruitOrdered[20];
    int qty;
    double orderPrice;
    double totalPrice;
};

string choice;
cout << "Do you want to purchase fruit (yes/no)? ";
cin >> choice;
cout << endl;

char order;
double orderQTY;

for (choice; choice == "yes"; choice)
{
    cout << "Which fruit would you like?" << endl << endl;
    cin >> order;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "How many pounds would you like?";
    cin >> orderQTY;
    custOrder order = //if for example they respond "apples" i want the resulting variable to be custOrder.apples
    {
        order,
        orderQTY,
        order.price,
        orderQTY * order.price
    };
    cout << "Do you want to purchase another fruit? ";
    cin >> choice;
    cout << endl;
}
cout << "Thanks for your business." << endl;
```

I know this is basic stuff, but I am completely lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use something like:

```
custOrder thisOrder;
thisOrder.order = order;
thisOrder.orderQTY = orderQTY;
```

so its really quite easy - you just access the members of a struct variable as variableName.member. Not sure about your structure type definition, I would be using:

```
typedef struct custOrder....
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I put this directly in I get the error

"Error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue" under the thisOrder portion of thisOrder.order

Comment: Yes of course, my example is rubbish in that respect. thisOrder.order is a char[20] (note that the order variable you read the input into has to be char[20] too, in the example its just char), so you would use strcpy to put a string into it thus: strcpy(thisOrder.order, order); as you cannot simply use = to assign a char[] string, sadly. But you can with std::string which is one of the reasons it's much to be preferred.

Comment: i changed all my char[20]s to std::string and it looks like it's working now, i won't know for sure until i figure out how to write the output portion of the program

Comment: Changing to std::string is a good move - you won't regret it - char[] is an abomination these days. Why not put a breakpoint into the code after the user entry is done? Then you can look at your variables & check that they are OK, and step through the code that stores the data to see that it is working too.

Comment: correction, in the order.fruitOrdered = order; i'm getting an error under the = that says

"no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are std::string = custOrder"

Comment: Well, I promise you std::string has an assignment operator, but in your error message it looks like the compiler thinks you are trying to assign a custOrder to a string. Have a hard look at your variable names - in your example code you had char order for the customer input which you have changed to a string, and later on a custOrder order. If it's still like that you need to change one of the variable names as having two variables with the same name will cause immense confusion, at best.

Comment: changed order to thisOrder and the error went away, thank you